# How to parse through JSON with [] brackets?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I'm parsing through JSON on a website like so (under a request.httpMethod = "GET" in Swift
):

```
  let example = json.data.first?.TShirtPrice
```

The JSON I'm getting is structured like so

```
{"returned":1,"data":[{"TShirtPrice":"5"}]}
```

But I have a new JSON set that is structured without [] brackets like so:

```
{"returned":1,"base":"USD","data":{"TShirtPrice":"3.448500"}}
```

The same exact code doesn't let me get the price of the shirt anymore -- what is the fix? Thank you!

**This is my code**

```
 if let data = data {

                    do {
                        let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from: data)


                        let price = json.data.first?.TShirtPrice


                        struct Root: Codable {
                            let data: [Datum]
                        }
                        struct Datum: Codable {
                            let TShirtPrice: String


                        }
```

Comment: Are you using json_decode ?

Comment: @AmitSharma Yes:    if let data = data {
                    
                    do {
                        let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from: data)

                    
                        let Price = json.data.first?.TShirtPrice

Comment: Hello @ChaseSmith so this new json response change is permanent or it can be either of those??

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar its permanent.

Comment: @ChaseSmith see the following answer it should help you to access the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data model is something as follows You can be using Struct or Class it's not an issue.

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let returned: Int?
    let base: String?
    let data: Price?
}

struct Price: Codable {
    let TShirtPrice: String? 
}
```

Sample JSON Sting is as follows

```
let jsonString = """
{
  "returned": 1,
  "base": "USD",
  "data": {
    "TShirtPrice": "3.448500"
  }
}
"""
```

You just have to change the way data is parsed by making change in data model as given above and way to access the data as given below

```
if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
    let myObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(myObject.data?.TShirtPrice)
}
```

**In your case it will look like this**

```
if let data = data {
    do {
        let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from: data)
        let Price = json.data?.TShirtPrice
    }
}
```

**What is changed here?**

As your price data was in format of Array the code was written accordingly and as per new data it's not an Array anymore so you have to adapt those changes app side also.

Comment: I kept the properties in data model as optional coz it depends on you. Can keep it optional if you are not sure whether the values will always there in response or not.

This helps to avoid unintentional crashes if some changes in response data

Comment: it's just for this case
As i am using local josn

Comment: I'm getting the following error: ERROR: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.})))

Comment: Is it possible to add you Model,json, and code snippet to parse it in the question it self?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207042/discussion-between-harshal-bhavsar-and-chase-smith).